# A finite field problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, fourier-analysis, finite-fields

$\mathbb F$ is finite field, $\mathbb A$ is a subset of $\mathbb F$, and $|\mathbb A|>|\mathbb F|^{\frac 34} $. Proof $\forall  x \in \mathbb F$, there exist $a,b,c,d,e,f\in\mathbb A$ that makes $x = ab+cd+ef$.

A possible route may be to use [Kneser's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser%27s_theorem_(combinatorics)) to get a handle on the available number of products $ab$, and then apply [Cauchy-Davenport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_sumset#Cauchy%E2%80%93Davenport_theorem) or Kneser again on the additive side. Can this be made to work, or is a different approach required?

Comment: Yeah, A  just a subset of F

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a lemma in the paper [Mordell's exponential sum estimate revisited](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Mordell's-exponential-sum-estimate-revisited-Bourgain/8f25d417c43762e696bbb7a25935a44891501080) by Jean Bourgain. The author proves it using Fourier analytic methods applied to finite abelian groups.

Comment: Of course, it could be possible to prove it using more 'direct' methods. But if you are willing to accept the theory of Fourier analysis on finite abelian groups/finite fields, it is quite a straightforward application of it. These are known as sum-product estimates.

Comment: I think this question is on an advanced level and it would be counter-productive to avoid Fourier analysis on finite abelian groups. I think, giving such a link is quite helpful (+1).